# Accessing agent computer in azure devops

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am new in **azure devops services**, and i am trying to run a pipeline that process an asp.net core application.

I have a task for restoring the project dependencies. Its code is  `dotnet Restore`
.

The piepeline fail on that command with this message :

> 1:5>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0. [D:\a\1\s\AspNetProjectOnDocker.csproj]
> Done executing task "NETSdkError" -- FAILED.
> 1:5>Done building target "_CheckForUnsupportedNETCoreVersion" in project "AspNetProjectOnDocker.csproj" -- FAILED.
> 1:5>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\AspNetProjectOnDocker.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target(s)) -- FAILED.
> 1>Done executing task "MSBuild" -- FAILED.
> 1>Done building target "_GenerateRestoreGraph" in project "AspNetProjectOnDocker.csproj" -- FAILED.
> 1>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\AspNetProjectOnDocker.csproj" (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.

**AspNetProjectOnDocker** is the name of my .net project

My Questions :

- How to access to the folder : **C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets** specified in the error message above.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, any update on this question, have you checked my answer, does my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Questions :
>
> How to access to the folder : C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets
> specified in the error message above.

Answer to your question:

This is not a folder, it is a file. You can access it via the following YAML pipeline definition.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- script: |
    echo Check target file
    C:
    cd C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets
    more Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets

  displayName: 'Check target file'

# if you encounter some issue such as can't find directory, you can use the following method to check what happens.

# - script: |
#     echo Check target file step by step
#     dir
#     C:
#     dir
#     cd Program Files
#     dir
#     cd dotnet
#     dir
#     cd sdk
#     dir
#     cd 5.0.410
#     dir
#     cd Sdks
#     dir
#     cd Microsoft.NET.Sdk
#     dir
#     cd targets
#     dir
#     more Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets

#   displayName: 'Check target file step by step'
```

Successfully get the file content:

[image]